# How to remove all special character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to remove all special character in string, here is my code:

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
```

But some of string have escape string so I can not remove, for example:

```
var str = "this is a string\";
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
```

I got error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL(…)"

How can I resolved it?

Comment: just use `var str = "this is a string\\";`

Comment: `str.replace` doesn't get reached at all, the parsing process terminates because it's not even valid javascript. `"this is a string\";` appears to have no right closing quote. Becuase `\"` is an escape-sequence for `"` character. \ character itself has to be escaped with \\ so that it doesn't escape anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra quote at the end of the string. When you add `\"` in the string the `"` is escaped and is part of the string, to delimit it, add an extra quote at the end.

```
var str = "this is a string\"";
```

Or, you can also use single quotes for string and use double quote inside it, there will be no need to escape it

```
var str = 'this is a string';
```

If you want to use `\` in string, you need to escape it by preceding another `\`.

```
var str = "this is a string\\";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code fragment.

```
var desired = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```